# How do I convert a MBR disk containing a Windows boot partition to a GPT disk while leaving the boot partition bootable?

Tags: windows, gpt, mbr

I have an existing Windows 7 64-bit boot partition on a 3 TB hard drive, which is an MBR disk. My BIOS is definitely a UEFI BIOS. The motherboard is a Asrock Z77E-ITX (see http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77E-ITX/) and I've updated it to the latest BIOS.

I'd like to create a single partition which is 3 TB in size while still

- maintaining all the same content in the boot partition
- being able to boot from the partition

Having a partition > 2 TB requires a GPT disk from what I've researched, but conversion from MBR to GPT apparently makes the boot partition unbootable? Is there a way to convert it to GPT without losing the ability to boot from the drive?

I can't seem to be able to find a single, straightforward answer to this. Is there a tool somewhere that can do this?

Comment: Do you know if your PC's BIOS is EFI/UEFI?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, I should have added that information initially.

Comment: Keep in mind Windows 7 *32-bit* can't boot from GPT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I migrate a Windows 10 from BIOS/MBR boot to UEFI/GPT without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200263/how-can-i-migrate-a-windows-10-from-bios-mbr-boot-to-uefi-gpt-without-reinstalli)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is maintaining bootability. Basically, you'll need to convert from MBR to GPT with `gdisk` and then install an EFI-mode boot loader for Windows. [This page](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) describes the process. Note that it's not risk-free, so be prepared to undo everything and recover or re-install Windows if things go south.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, yes there's some tools : [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html), [DISKPART](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671.aspx) (etc). Also, it's seem that you'll find that you looking for with them. According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/301249/convert-mbr-to-gpt-partition-format).

PS : I can't do more (give feedback). I just recently discover the existence of those tools.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I also came across something similar at http://serverfault.com/questions/301249/convert-mbr-to-gpt-partition-format - I'm just wondering if anyone has tried it on a bootable partition and checked if the partition remained bootable and if not, if it was possible to make it bootable.