# Laptop already has 4 partitions - need an extra one

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am trying to dual-boot my laptop with linux, which requires you to add a partition where the OS will be installed, however, my laptop (which runs Windows 10) already has these 4 partitions (I have never added any):

- 100mb - Healthy (EFI System Partition)
- ACER (C:) - 465.20 GB NTFS - Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)
- 500mb - Healthy (Recovery Partition)
- Data (D:) - 465.71 GB NTFS - Healthy (Primary Partition)

Is it possible for me to delete any of these partitions, or is there a work around so I can add another partition for the linux boot?

Comment: You may shrink the primary partitions.

Comment: But you can only have 4 partitions right?

Comment: You can only have 4 partitions on an MBR partitioned disk (default on BIOS based firmware), but the fact that you have an EFI partition shows you have a UEFI firmware where the default partition scheme is GPT which allows more partitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I migrate a Windows 10 from BIOS/MBR boot to UEFI/GPT without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200263/how-can-i-migrate-a-windows-10-from-bios-mbr-boot-to-uefi-gpt-without-reinstalli).  In order to use this tool you will likely have to delete your data partition.  Any tool to convert MBR to GPT would require a similar process by the way.  However, MBR2GPT is the supported method by Microsoft, which means it is less prone to mistakes.  If you are already using GPT then you can disregard this duplicate close vote.

Comment: Although converting from BIOS/MBR to EFI/GPT *might* be a useful solution to Shawn's issue, chances are it's unnecessary; and even if it would be a useful solution, it's not the only one. Thus, this question really is not a duplicate of the one Ramhound suggests as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mokubai, MBR disks can have ESPs; they're type code 0xEF on MBR. That said, ESPs are uncommon on MBR disks, so your diagnosis is *probably* correct. My answer elaborates on this.

Answer (score 1):

You say your computer runs Windows 10 and that its first partition is an EFI System Partition (ESP). This combination *strongly* suggests that it's currently booting in EFI mode from a GPT disk. If so, there is no 4-primary-partition limit, and you can create up to 124 more partitions on the disk before you hit the 128-partition limit of GPT -- and that limit can be raised, if necessary.

If my inference is wrong, you can convert a partition from primary to logical form with some partitioning tools. The one with which I'm most familiar is my own [FixParts,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) which comes with most Linux distributions in a package called `gdisk` or `gptfdisk`. Some commercial Windows tools can do the job, too, but I'm not familiar with the details. Note that there are some caveats and limitations, which probably vary from one program to another; see the documentation for whatever you're using for the details.

See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for information on determining your current boot mode.