# How can I solve this MBR2GPT (Cannot find OS Partition) Issue?

Tags: boot, partitioning, bios, mbr, windows-11

According to [How can I migrate a Windows 10 from BIOS/MBR boot to UEFI/GPT without reinstalling?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200263/how-can-i-migrate-a-windows-10-from-bios-mbr-boot-to-uefi-gpt-without-reinstalli/) I can convert my system disk to GPT without reinstalling and losing data using the MBR2GPT tool, provided by Windows 10 Home. I'm also using Windows 10 Home at the moment.

I tried and I got an error about "not finding the OS partition".

This is the complete log`

```
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR2GPT was explicitly asked to run in full OS mode.
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR2GPT: Attempting to validate disk 1
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR2GPT: Initial partition information
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         ===========================================================
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         Partition layout for disk: 1
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         Partition style          : MBR
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR signature: 1316942726
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         Number of partitions     : 2
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Number: 1
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                                Type: 7
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                                Boot: Yes
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                               Style: 0
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Offset: 1048576
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Length: 119463823872
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{4e7ef386-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                               Drive: C:\
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk1\Partition1
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         ===================PARTITION===============================
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Number: 2
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                                Type: 39
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                                Boot: No
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                          Recognized: Yes
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                               Style: 0
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Offset: 119466360832
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Length: 565182464
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                              Volume: \\?\Volume{4e7ef386-0000-0000-0000-c0d01b000000}\
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                               Drive: None
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                             NT Path: \Device\HardDisk1\Partition2
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         ===========================================================
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         ESP partition size will be 104857600
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         BCD: Opening store. Flags: 0x0
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         BCD: Store path: "\??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition1\Boot\BCD"
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         BCD: Failed to load hive into key BCD00000000 from \??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition1\Boot\BCD. Status: c000000f
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Info                         BCD: BcdOpenStore: Failed to add store from file \??\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition1\Boot\BCD. StoreFlags: 0x0 Status: c000000f
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Error                        FindOSPartitions: Cannot open BCD for boot volume. Error: 0xC000000F
2021-11-19 14:26:25, Error   

                 Cannot find OS partition(s) for disk 1
```

bcdedit logs

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {b8240ef0-c1cb-11ea-93ac-b1ed93ed4fd8}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1e484ced-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
displaymessageoverride  CommandPrompt
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {b8240ef0-c1cb-11ea-93ac-b1ed93ed4fd8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

with the enum all command line

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {b8240ef0-c1cb-11ea-93ac-b1ed93ed4fd8}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {1e484ced-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
device                  ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{1e484cee-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{1e484cee-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1e484ced-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
displaymessageoverride  CommandPrompt
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {b8240ef0-c1cb-11ea-93ac-b1ed93ed4fd8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {b8240ef0-c1cb-11ea-93ac-b1ed93ed4fd8}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winresume.exe
description             Windows Resume Application
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1e484ced-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
filedevice              partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
bootmenupolicy          Standard
debugoptionenabled      No

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \boot\memtest.exe
description             Windows Memory Diagnostic
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
debugtype               Local

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}

Device options
--------------
identifier              {1e484cee-b56e-11ea-87fc-93f4e158aa1d}
description             Windows Recovery
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
```

I don't know why this is happening as Windows 10 is booting fine but I want to upgrade to windows 11. Any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Provide us a screenshot of the partitions within Disk Manager. My guess the partition responsible for booting your system is on a different disk than the OS. The screenshot will confirm this theory, or otherwise, explain the reason your disk partition layout makes it ineligible for MBR2GPT.

Comment: This ^^^ or it may need different settings in UEFI. Changing modes isn't as simple as the guide you follow makes it to be. Windows has strict requirements: MBR (as it was) for BIOS/Legacy mode and GPT (after mbr2gpt) for UEFI mode.